# REST API Design - Create Resource By Loading By ID

Tags: rest, restful-url, api-design

My REST service needs to support the ability to load/reload a resource vs. outright create it.

API thus far:

```
GET /books
GET /books/12345
DELETE /books/12345
```

A book looks something like:

```
{"id": 12345, "title": "three little bears", "author": ...}
```

It's unclear as to whether

```
Request:  PUT /books/12345
Response: HTTP 204 No Content
```

or

```
Request:  POST /books
Payload:  {"id": 12345}
Response: HTTP 201 Created, Location: /books/12345
```

is the better approach to "load"/"reload" the book.

Details: The "load"/"reload" will consult a database to retrieve the book by id, and place the result in a persistent cache. The cache is what is consulted for the GET requests. The book's attributes can change in the database, meaning a "load"/"reload" isn't idempotent. Only an admin will be able to use the load/reload and delete operations.

I *believe* the correct approach is a POST, because a PUT is supposed to be idempotent. However, a POST seems odd because multiple POSTs against /book for id=12345 will only result in a single resource being created (albeit re-created multiple times)

I've considered the additional options below, but they seem more egregious:

```
* POST /books/12345/load
* POST /books/load, with payload {"id": 12345}
* POST /load/book, with payload {"id": 12345}
```

Thoughts?

To complicate matters further, I'd also like to offer an asynchronous load/reload operation, but i don't want to create an operation/job resource that the user can track, I just want a fire-and-forget.

Example: For Book 12345, load/reload asynchronously into the cache. I only need the service to respond with a HTTP 202 Accepted and that's sufficient. No need to ever ask what the progress of the load/reload.

TL;DR: I'm building a REST service to front a cache of books. The load/reload and delete operations can only be executed by an admin, whereas GET is open for all. The load/reload operation should load/reload the record from the database.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correct, you have a

- origin
- database
- clients

If a client `GET`s a `book`, he fetches the resource from the database.
The database doesn't know if this `book` is altered in the meantime, it serves an outdated version? Therefore you want the client to `POST` or `PUT` the resource to force the database to fetch the entry again from the origin?

Think about this:

The origin caches its content, the database caches its content and the client caches too.

If a user would hit F5 the client would reload the resource, right?
Is this a good behaviour? no.
Would it be better for the client to check wether the resource is outdated or not and only fetch if neccessary? yes.
This could be achieved by sending a `HTTP-HEAD` asking the server for the date of the last modification, if the clients retrieval-date is older he needs to fetch again, otherwise he can serve from cache.

Same would apply for the databse/origin-constellation. The database needs to validate its content is still the latest for the request and serve it or fetch it from the origin, update the caches and serve the new entry.

So the client would still `GET` the resoure, what would be accurate if he doesn't want to alter the resource in any way.

Comment: I've updated the description to be a bit more clear. In short: I'm building a REST service to front a cache of books. The load/reload and delete operations can only be executed by an admin, whereas GET is open for all. The load/reload operation should load/reload the record from the database of origin and place it into the cache. Note: Agreed that HEAD would be a useful addition.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you shouldn't use action names within resource paths (something like `/books/12345/reload`, ...) since it's not really RESTful. That said, I agree with you that a method `POST` is the right method to use.

IMO, you should use a method `POST` for the resource path `/books/12345`. It will correspond to an action load / reload and can be asynchronous, i.e. return a status code `202è. If you already have a method`POST` for this resource, you should consider to use the strategy described in this blog post: https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/03/20/handling-multiple-actions-for-a-post-method/.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry